Directus : datetime validation forcing End Date to be greater than Start Date field
I have a form in Directus to reserve a company car.
The user has to enter Start date ( called Inicio) and End Date (called Fim)
The form must grant that End Date(Fim) is greater than Start Date(Inicio)
According to the image just writting Inicio in the validation Formula does not work.
I get
"Unexpected Error"
[Internal Server Error]

How do i code the validation to force the End Date to be greater than Start Date
